# How to change a Button's tab stop dashed border color in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, button

In keyboard navigation, when a button is selected, it has a dashed border. How to change its color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `FocusVisualStyle`.  If you set this to null, you can hide the dashed border.  In your case, you want to change the color.  What you would do would be to create a new style and apply it to the `FocusVisualStyle`.

Here is an MSDN article that shows you how to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744790.aspx

The basic code they list is as follows:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="MyFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Rectangle Margin="-2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Red" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<StackPanel Background="Ivory" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Canvas Width="10"/>
  <Button Width="100" Height="30" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisual}">
    Focus Here</Button>
  <Canvas Width="100"/>
  <Button Width="100" Height="30" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisual}">
    Focus Here</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: When trying to abolish the style completely, bare in mind that `ContentControl` and `ItemsControl` also use `FocusVisualStyle`, so adding `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` to those instances may also be required.