# How can I programmatically select the focused element?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a page on which there are several focusable elements(Buttons, Images, ...) generated some statically in XAML, some dynamically in code behind. On this page, pressing the tab key will make the elements focused one by one. That means the dotted lined gets displayed around the current element. Now, I would like to make the current focused element, selected too. That means to display the blueish line around it too. So as the focused moves, so does the selected

How can I do that in the C# code-behind?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to really set `IsFocused` to true, or just want the element to look like its focused?

Comment: Some item's that can be focused, can't be selected, like a Grid for example.  Anyways, you would need to probably use [`FocusManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to manage what get's selected.  Also since focus can only be on control at a time, you can only have one selected item at a time.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that we might not be understanding your question properly. Buttons and images don't have a concept of being "Selected" in WPF if I'm not mistaken. Are you just saying that instead of a dotted line around your element (whatever type they may be) when focused, you want a blue line instead?

Comment: If they don't have the concept of Selected then perhaps what I saw was them being added to a listbox.

Comment: @WaterfrVilla My answer works if you want to add them to a listbox. Even if you're dynamically constructing and adding elements to the listbox in code behind. Might have to edit the ItemContainerStyle to get a blue border like you want, though.

Comment: Your solution must be by code-behind?

Answer (score 10):

I would say the best way to do it perhaps varies depending on what kinds of focusable elements you have? If you want to do this for listboxitem's, you can do this with only xaml like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>
        Blah
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

A similar style trigger can be applied for other focusable and selectable elements as well.

Comment: There are several elements in that page. If I set the Selector.IsSelected of all of them at the xaml file then which one will be selected? I was wondering how we can do this in the code behind?

Comment: @WaterfrVilla If there are several elements on the page, whichever element currently has focus will be selected. Is this not the behavior you desire? Why do you specifically want to do it in code behind? I feel like this is one of the things that are done more cleanly if done in xaml.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? The original question did not state that he wanted to do it in code behind. I answered it based on the original prompt.

Comment: Sorry, yes that was the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Edited:

I think what you just need is change the dotted line on TabStop. That broken line is indicative of selected state. So, it is selected already. This 'select the focused element' statement does not make any sense since if you are referring to TabStop, it is indeed already selected. You can test it by pressing the Tab and then whichever has the dotted line, if it is a button and hit enter, it will do the Click event (if there is ever a handler behind it).

What you need is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597236/how-to-change-a-buttons-tab-stop-dashed-border-color-in-wpf).

If you want to do it in code behind, add this to the Resource of your XAML.

```
<Style x:Key="MyFocusVisual">
      <Setter Property="Control.Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                   <Rectangle Margin="-2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Blue" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
....
 myButton.FocusVisualStyle = (Style)FindResource("MyFocusVisual");
```

If you do not have an access to the XAML, I think from this, you can figure out how to add a style in code-behind and add the style to the button. Now, I am obviously contradicting myself here, since you are aiming for a code-behind, it is impossible not to have access to the XAML right? It is still practical to add this via XAML than code behind.

Comment: Tabs are special case. I ask for other elements like buttons images e

Answer (score 3):

I would ensure that every element is either a button or the template of a button. This way the "IsTabStop" can be used, or the elements can be focused.
Using the solution of MrsEd you can get the item to be correctly bordered:

```
<Button x:Class="Visualisation.UserControlButtonImage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             IsTabStop="True">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
           <Grid>
               <Image/> 
           </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did in the xml. I added **PreviewGotKeyboardFocus** to my window

```
             PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="FrmBase_OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus"
```

Use  **PreviewGotKeyboardFocus** on the root element (usercontrol or window) to handle the focus event on every child control.

Code behind

```
private void FrmBase_OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic item = e.NewFocus;
        item.IsSelected = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of elements you are referring to, are not all selectable.

You want this in C#, and some elements will be added dynamically, and the keyboard will tab through the elements. I suggest keeping track of your focused items and then implementing a method that does whatever it is you are trying to do based on the current focused element. [Using the keyboard focus method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focus(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected override void OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var focusedElement = e.Source as IInputElement;
    // Do something here
}
```